# Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate is always null

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net core website deployed on Azure app service for Linux.

In the controller, I am trying to get the client certificate like below:

```
var callerCertificate = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
```

I always get `callerCertificate` as *null*. 
I have tried `await Request.HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync()` with same result *null*.

My website webhost creation looks like below:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSerilog();
```

I have also set SSL setting for the website (in Azure) as below:

[image]

The client side caller is a net462 project that uses `Microsoft.Rest.CertificateCredentials` to set the certificate to HTTP request.

```
var cred = new CertificateCredentials(_deviceCertificate)
...
await this.cred.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(_httpRequest, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I solved via exchanging certificate file.
Look description here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833178/client-certificate-is-always-null/55279563#55279563](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279563/4928462)

Comment: @Tany are you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @AjayYadav Yeah. Look at my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I referred that but still getting the certificate is null.

Comment: .net 5 works with:
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
            {
                o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o => 
                o.ClientCertificateMode = 
                ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate);
            });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:
I am able to get the client certificate from header

> string clientCertFromHeader = Request.Headers["X-ARR-ClientCert"];

Though, it is still a mystery as to why Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate is not giving the certificate.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to add the certificate using `HttpClient` directly instead of using `Microsoft.Rest.CertificateCredential`.

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(_deviceCertificate);

var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
var result = client.GetAsync("https://yourservice").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

You may also need to configure the SSL protocol (SSL2, SSL3, TLS, etc.):

```
clientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls;
```

Comment: The aim of what I need to achieve is to keep the client side same and migrate the existing asp.net webapi website to a asp.net core website. Requiring the client to change would be a big breaking change, which I am trying to avoid. Nevertheless, I am going to try what you suggested and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah, at least it may give you more info about the underlying problem. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: It did not help. Controller is still not getting the certificate. :(