# Client certificate is always null

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core-webapi, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a certificate installed under **Personal** as well as **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**

Have tried using this bit of code to post to an endpoint:

```
public void Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var clientCert = LoadFromStore("MyThumbprint");
            var requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();

            requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

            var client = new HttpClient(requestHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44430/")
            };

            var response = client.GetAsync("api/test").Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while executing the test code: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Upon inspection the **.ClientCertificate** property is always null.

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        var clientCertInRequest = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
        if (clientCertInRequest != null) return Ok();

        return BadRequest("No certificate found");
    }
```

}

Wondering if anyone has come across this issue before or know a way around posting a certificate to webapi endpoint and be able to retrieve and validate?

Many thanks

Comment: Just for completeness of the question, please, add the code of the method LoadFromStore

Answer (score 2):

.Net 6:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestrel =>
{
    kestrel.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(https => https.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate);
});
```

Older Versions:

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
            {
                o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o => 
                o.ClientCertificateMode = 
                ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you use **real IIS** and not express and Disable TLS 1.3.
2. Configure IIS so that it accepts certificates

- [IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/)
- [Client Certificate Mapping Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication)

3. Configure mapped certificates in config or active directory
4. Try the request in the browser and see if a certificate selection dialog pops up

- if not diagnose based on HTTP Error sub status code
- if so run your code again

Answer (score 0):

You must know, that on server-side in response certificate is depends on certificate type / certificate content.
I had same issue, when I pushed **self-signed certificate** (generated locally in IIS): on server in request certificate was always null.
But when I pushed **normal (public) certificate**, with chain hierarchy - I was surprised cause I received certificate!!

- [example of IIS self-signed certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6quE.png)

So I recommend to generate **public certificate** for the first time at free Certificate authorized centers, such as https://www.sslforfree.com/

- [certificate example of current site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRhLl.png)
- Also I recommend you to look at MS source mode of [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.x509certificate2](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509certificate2.cs) and other classes!